# Symfony2 double inner join with doctrine 2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, inner-join

well i'm having a problem and hope you can help me
i have 3 tables in my database (project , variable , branding )
variable has idBranding as foreign key and idVariable as primary key
branding has idProject as foreign key and idBranding as primary key
i need to display the variable depending on the project and i did a DAO function for that

> public function getAllTagByProject($idProject) {
>
> ```
>    return $this->getRepository()->createQueryBuilder('v')
>
>                    ->innerJoin('v.Branding', 'b')
>
>                    ->innerJoin('b.Project', 'p')
>
>                    ->where('v.Project = :project')
>
>                    ->setParameter("project", $idProject)
>
>                    ->getQuery()->getResult();
> ```
>
> }

and here is what i get

[image]

first time posting on this forum hope you guys will be able to help
i found some similar topics but didn't help me solve my problem
thanks

Comment: I guess that fields in Variable entity are named `branding` and `project`. Join  and where condition should use name of field in PHP class, not a name of column in database. I would try `innerJoin('v.branding')`, `innerJoin('b.project)` and `where('v.project')`.
Maybe your where condition is wrong. It looks like that project belongs to branding, so I would expect `where('b.project')`.

Comment: it says:      
 [Semantical Error] line 0, col 71 near 'b INNER JOIN': Error: Class Project\AdminBundle\Entity\Variable has no association named Branding,     
at first i did it like that but to match the association i changed into idBranding

Comment: Add definition of your classes (only relevant mapped fields without methods). It's hard to guess query without mapping.